# Inserting a relationship object into a core data object automatically inserts it multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode5

I have 2 entities: Project and Task. A project can have many tasks. one-to-many relationship.

I have a table view controller that lists all the tasks of a selected project. And another view controller for adding a new task to the given project. The problem is that when adding new tasks, they are inserted more than once, sometimes twice sometimes three times.

I realised that: 
the first time a task is added, 1 task is added, second time a task is added, 2 tasks are added, the 3rd task, 3 tasks are added and so on.

I don't know where the problem lies exactly.

Please somebody help.

The AddTaskViewController has a modal segue from the TasksTableViewController

TasksTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Project.h"
#import "Task.h"

@interface MATasksTableViewController : UITableViewController


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *passedPath;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Project *project;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *taskTitleString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tasksArray;

@end
```

TasksTableViewController.m

```
#import "MATasksTableViewController.h"
#import "Project.h"
#import "Task.h"
#import "MACoreDataStack.h"
#import "MAAddTaskViewController.h"

@interface MATasksTableViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation MATasksTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    _project = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:_passedPath];
    _tasksArray = [_project.task allObjects];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //return [_tasksArray count];
    return [_tasksArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    Task *t = [_tasksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = t.title;

    return cell;
}


-(NSFetchRequest *)projectListFetchRequest {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Project"];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dueDate" ascending:YES]];

    return fetchRequest;
}

-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if(_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    MACoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [MACoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self projectListFetchRequest];
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        MACoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [MACoreDataStack defaultStack];
        Task *t = [_tasksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_project removeTaskObject:t];
        [coreDataStack saveContext];
        [self performFetchAgain];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AddTaskSegue"]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        MAAddTaskViewController *destinationVC = [navController topViewController];
        destinationVC.project = self.project;
        destinationVC.firstViewController = self;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(didPressDoneAndDismissController)
                                                     name:@"doneWasPressedInSecondView"
                                                   object:nil];

    }
}

-(void)didPressDoneAndDismissController {
    MACoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [MACoreDataStack defaultStack];
    Task *task = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Task" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];
    task.title = self.taskTitleString;
    [self.project addTaskObject:task];
    [coreDataStack saveContext];
    [self performFetchAgain];
}

-(void)performFetchAgain {
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    _project = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:_passedPath];
    _tasksArray = [_project.task allObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

AddTaskViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Project.h"
#import "MATasksTableViewController.h"


@interface MAAddTaskViewController : UIViewController {
    Project *project;
    MATasksTableViewController *firstViewController;
}


@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;

@property (strong, nonatomic)  MATasksTableViewController *firstViewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Project *project;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *tasks;

@end
```

AddTaskViewController.m

```
#import "MAAddTaskViewController.h"
#import "Project.h"
#import "Task.h"
#import "MACoreDataStack.h"

@interface MAAddTaskViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation MAAddTaskViewController
@synthesize project;
@synthesize tasks;
@synthesize firstViewController;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)createNewTask {

    NSString* taskTitle = self.textField.text;
    self.firstViewController.taskTitleString = taskTitle;
}

-(void)dismissSelf {
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)doneWasPressed:(id)sender {
    [self createNewTask];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"doneWasPressedInSecondView"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:nil];
    [self dismissSelf];
}
- (IBAction)cancelWasPressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissSelf];
}

@end
```

Comment: Welcome to SOF. You should not dump the code of an entire class. It is customary here that you just post the code you think is relevant and comment on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I realised that: the first time a task is added, 1 task is added, second time a task is added, 2 tasks are added, the 3rd task, 3 tasks are added and so on.

When you `prepareForSegue` you do this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didPressDoneAndDismissController)
                                                 name:@"doneWasPressedInSecondView"
                                               object:nil];
```

You do that every time you prepare for the segue but you never remove `self` as an observer. If you register multiple times but never remove the registration, you can get the notification multiple times.

Every time you receive the notification, you create a new managed object. This is a side effect of the above. You need to do at least one of the following, though really you should do both:

- Register for that notification **once** instead of every time you `prepareForSegue`.
- Remove `self` as an observer of this notification when you no longer care about receiving it.